# jQuery Tabs - Following External Links

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have jQuery Tabs setup, but am trying to get a Tab to follow an external link.

I have tried to use the code from jQuery, but the URL still loads via Ajax instead of redirecting the browser to the url:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...follow_a_tab.27s_URL_instead_of_loading_its_content_via_ajax

Current code:

```
 $(function() {
            $('#rotate > ul').tabs({
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    var url = $.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs');
                    if( url ) {
                        location.href = url;
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: when you code runs, can you put a breakpoint in (aka  "debugger;" statement) and tell me the value of url at the time of the if() statement?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code:

```
$(function() {
     $('#rotate').tabs({
       select: function(event, ui) {
           var url = $.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs');
           if(typeof(url) != "undefined" ) {
               location.href = url;
           }
        }
     });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ejupil